# Can LinkedIn API provide a count of the number of connect requests a user sends each day?

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there a way to use the LinkedIn API to get a count of the number of connect requests sent each day?

It would be ideal if we could also find out how many people accepted - but I think that's easier, since we can just grab the number of connections and subtract the number from the day before.

Has anyone tried to do anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we don't support a way for you to get the information you are looking for via the API.